# How to see the complete blockUI message if it's height is larger than window's height?

Tags: jquery, position, draggable, scrollable, jquery-blockui

I have a jquery blockUI message whose height is larger than some window sizes.
I am unable to see the bottom part of the message in that case. If I drag the message to top, and if it's header goes beyond the top of screen, then the user is blocked and cannot drag it down again. Any help would be great. thanks.